# Trouble using nth-child to select elements added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

My application allows users to add / remove objects to the DOM. (Click a shape to add one, click the added-shape to remove it.)

This works correctly, however now I would like to be able to access these added shapes and manipulate them.

**(Attempt to) Loop through nth-child**

```
for(i=0; i<this.shape.length; i++) {
    $('#selected_shape_table:nth-child('+i+')').html("test"); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="selected_shape_table">

</table>
```

**(Add shapes to table originally)**

```
$('.shape').click(function() {
    var typeOfShape = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#selected_shape_table').append('<td><div id="' + typeOfShape + '" class=selected_shape"> + typeOfShape + '</div></td>'); 
});
```

Comment: ShimmerGeek, of you're willing to create a simple fiddle illustrating your issue (creating elements) I'm willing to show you how to re-write it in a way I _believe_ is correct. Storing your information in an actual model and not the dom. Separating what you have and what you want to present, and handling such events. Up to you.

Comment: What if you insert the loop in your click function, after the append?

Comment: Bram what do you mean?

Comment: Isnt that appending only the `id` of the clicked shape?

Comment: Bah, yeah sorry I simplified it a little from my full code. It appends `'<td><div id="' + typeOfShape + '" class=selected_shape"> + typeOfShape + '</div></td>`

Comment: `ID's` must be unique, so if you can add multiple time the same form, you should place an id..

Comment: IDs do not have to be unique, it is simply convention for them to be.

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: No, the spec [says that they have to be unique](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute). `$('#foo')` won't select more than one element with an id of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#selected_shape_table:nth-child(2)` selects the third `#selected_shape_table` element, which isn't what you're trying to do.

jQuery has the [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
$('#selected_shape_table *').eq(i).html('test');
```

Also, make sure you use event delegation or put the event listener code after the loop.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I misread the documentation for `:nth-child` and assumed it was the nth-child of the element (as in `element:nth-child`) - whoops!

Comment: I just realised that this selects the full `<td><div>stuff</div><td>` when I only want to select the <div> - how should I select this? 

(Sorry if that's a silly question, still trying to get my head around element selectors)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: Add on a `.find('div')`.

Comment: Fantastic, cheers! :) 

Do you know of any resources useful for understanding jQuery selectors better? I've looked at the W3Schools list but I'm wondering if there are any other resources available that you know of to help it 'stick' better :)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: They're just CSS selectors with a few custom additions (`:eq`, `:hidden`, `:checkbox`, etc.), so there are a ton of resources if you look for CSS selectors instead of jQuery selectors. The syntax isn't complex at all.

Comment: Okedoke. Cheers again! :) I really appreciate the help!